# Fastest way of comparing intersections of sets and returning the dictionary key which contains the set belonging to the biggest intersection

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization, set

I have an algorithm for creating a maximal clique cover but it is too slow. For each step I need to compare intersections between a main set, and the sets obtained from the dictionary keys of the main set.

Right now I have a dictionary of sets:

```
edges = { 1:{2,3},
        2:{1,3},
        3:{1,2}}
```

And a main `set: {1,2}` (The length increases with each step)

```
intersection_C = {1,2}
```

For the next iteration of this instance it will be:
choose the dictionary key (from elements in main set) which gives you the largest intersection.

In other words: compare the intersections of the set `edges[1]` intersected with the set intersection_C, and the intersection of the set `edges[2]` intersected with intersection_C. Then choose the key which provided the largest (longest length) intersection. I need to keep both the final resulting intersection and the key which provided the largest intersection.

The key is added to a list C, and the final intersection will become the new main set

What is the fastest way I can do this?

My current algorithm for solving the subproblem is:

```
best = 0  #longest found length param
for node in intersection_C: #looping through elements of main set
    new = intersection_C.intersection(edges[node])   #new intersection'
    if len(new) >= best:          #comparing  
        candidate = node          #saving key
        best = len(new)          #updating best length
        best_intersection = new     #Saving best found intersection
    del new
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine a faster algorithm, but we can shorten the notation of your current one:

```
candidate = max(intersection_C, key = lambda node: len(intersection_C & edges[node]))
best_intersection = intersection_C & edges[candidate]
```

Comment: You might be right, do you believe using another language like C++ is able to find intersections faster? Or is it already written fast

Comment: It may well be that a C++ implementation is faster, though it certainly depends on the amount of data whether porting would be worthwhile. But since this here is only a subproblem, it could make sense to have a broader look at the superproblem, also with more representative data that would allow doing benchmarks and tests of optimizations at other places.